# Take Last n Items from a Grouped and Ordered List using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq-group

I have a list of Forms, and in this list the forms with the same **Title** denotes the different version of the that form, the one with closest **Creation Time** (which is `DateTime` type) is newer version.

So I want to select each forms last n versions using entity framework code. I used this but it still brings me the first (oldest) n versions.

```
List<Forms> dbResult = entities.Forms.OrderByDescending(e => e.CreationDate)
                                     .GroupBy(e => e.Title)
                                     .SelectMany(e => e.Take(n))
                                     .ToList();
```

Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = entities.Forms
            .GroupBy( x => x.Title )
            .SelectMany( g => g.OrderByDescending(v => v.CreationDate).Take(1) );
```

This would return you forms of same title with maximum CreationDate. You can do additional filtering to take n items and order them in any way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked perfectly. I used it as;

`List<Forms> dbResult = entities.Forms.GroupBy(e => e.Title).SelectMany(e => e.OrderByDescending(e => e.CreationDate).Take(3)).ToList();`

Can you tell me about the orderBy usage in selectMany?

Comment: Combination of SelectMany and OrderBy is there to do inner select to get item with max CreationDate. So not sure if you should do "take(3)" there. I would do another .Take(3) after SelectMany to get only 3 forms.

Comment: It worked as I wanted it to be, thanks again for the explanation.

Comment: I red you question again. And yes, you were correct. That would return you 3 latest Forms of same title.